# Find row number of the next value group in a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with values grouped as below:

```
import pandas
A = pandas.DataFrame([['a',0],['b',1],['ba',1],['c',2],['cd',2],columns=['value','group'],index=[22,23,11,12,13])
A
Out[28]: 
   value  group
22     a      0
23     b      1
11    ba      1
12     c      2
13    cd      2
```

I track the row number with respect to groups:

```
current_row_index = 1
current_group = A['group'].values[current_row_index]
current_group
Out[31]: 1
```

Now I would like to jump to the row number corresponding to the next group. I know I can do it by converting the pandas dataframe to a list:

```
list(A['group']==current_group+1).index(True)
Out[32]: 3
```

I am hesitating jumping between different datatypes, `pandas.DataFrame` and `list` and therefore I would like to find a `pandas` way to find the first row number corresponding to the row number of the next group.

Comment: which row do you track? what do you mean by 'row position'?

Comment: I am not using `A.index`, as you can see, it is not in order. Therefore, I am tracking the row position of the data.

Comment: why do not you reset the index, groupby group and get the index value of first row in each group?

Comment: I am sorry about the inaccurate use of terms row position/row index. I would like to track the row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example, I assume that you want the row number (not the row index).
You can use `numpy`:

```
current_group = 1
indices = np.where(A.group == current_group+1)[0]
```

Output:

```
array([3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


A = pd.DataFrame([['a',0],['b',1],['ba',1],['c',2],['cd',2]],columns=['value','group'],index=[22,23,11,12,13])

A = A.reset_index()

def get_first_row_index(g):
    g['first_index'] = g.index.values.tolist()[0]
    return g

A = A.groupby('group').apply(lambda g: get_first_row_index(g))
```

**OUT**

```
   index value  group  first_index
0     22     a      0            0
1     23     b      1            1
2     11    ba      1            1
3     12     c      2            3
4     13    cd      2            3
```

Comment: I like the idea to add "first_index" as an own column. Although there is `to_list()` in this answer.

Comment: ...   A['first_index'].tolist() or whatever other column after transformation is needed.